# How to execute a javascript every time i open a specific website in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, automation, greasemonkey

Actually, the problem is every time i access zedge.net i have to select my phone from the list. Now, what i can do is, once i click on 'no phone selected' i can write:   `javascript:zlibQuicklinkPhone(2, 1476, 0);` in address bar and pressing Return key will select my phone. But i want this to be done automatically. How can i do this?

**Note**: i am not using greasemonkey, but if this problem can't be solved without it, then i can install that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a plan to use greasemonkey, install it and

1. create "New User Script"
2. give it a name, and set Includes `http://zedge.net/*`
3. in post body,

   1. set checkbox of 'no phone selected' to true with script
   2. and on next line `zlibQuicklinkPhone(2, 1476, 0);`

basically thats all.

Comment: is it so easy? i will do that. Just a question, Is greasemonkey a memory hogger? i have read it somewhere.

Comment: Memory usage depends on the script, if you do simple task, thats should not be problem. And if you can provide `no phone selected` html parts in your question, I could add some codes to in 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the javascript into a bookmarklet: Create a new bookmark and replace the http link with our javascript (including the "javascript:" part). When you place the bookmarklet in the toolbar, your phone number is just one click away. It's not automatic, but it's the best you can do without GM.

Comment: This is a good point. Could the bookmarklet pull up the page he needs too? Then it's just one click, instead of, nav to page and then click.

Comment: actually i am already using bookmarklet. but that is not the kind of solution i needed